# Javascript generated HTML code calling knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Not sure if this is possible but here it goes.

I have an app with two main files - a javascript file and an HTML file and i'm using knockout.js, bootstrap and jquery.

Within a function in the js file, I generate an html form. I can't have the form in the html file as invisible - it has to be generated within the js file.

The problem is, I render buttons on the form which call knockout functions which are in the js file but they just don't work. I can reference these buttons using javascipt but this doesn't work as I need to pass the knockout model to the form.

Code is as follows:

Within the js file:

```
    self.helloFunction = function () {
         alert("Hello World");
}
```

Within the html file (which works as expected):

```
<div>
<input type="image" src="/Images/Buttons/edit.png" data-bind="click: $root.helloFunction" class="input-sm">
</div>
```

Within the JS file (which won't make the call back to helloFunction):

```
var helloWorld = '<div>' +
'<input type="image" src="/Images/Buttons/edit.png" data-bind="click: '$root.helloFunction" title="Hi" class="input-sm">' +
'</div>';

//display the html on the page:
displayForm(helloWorld);
```

It displays well, the title and image show, the bootstrap formatting is applied....it's just the knockout call (to helloWorld) that doesn't respond.

Is it possible going back and calling my knockout function?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Side note: Your JavaScript has a syntax error in it, an extra `'` before `$root.helloFunction`. You've said the button shows up, so I assume that's not in your real code.

Comment: Yep sorry just a typo as this is only a subset of data that I hand typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add content to the page *not* using Knockout after calling `applyBindings`, Knockout has no way of knowing it has to process those elements. To make it do that, you need to tell Knockout to apply bindings to those new elements, using `applyBindings` (but being careful to avoid calling it twice on the same element) or the undocumented `applyBindingsToNode` or `applyBindingsToDescendants`.

Example:

```js
var vm = {
  msg1: ko.observable("Hi there"),
  msg2: ko.observable("This was bound later; click me!"),
  clicker: function() {
    alert("clicker was clicked!");
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
setTimeout(function() {
  var newContent = $('<input type="button" data-bind="value: msg2, click: clicker">');
  newContent.appendTo("#container");
  ko.applyBindings(vm, newContent[0]);
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div data-bind="text: msg1"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```